# How to ensure text starts on the same line as enumeration?

Tags: formatting, lists, enumerate, enumitem

**Context**

I am quite new to LaTeX and am trying to write my assignment using it, but I am having some issues with formatting.

Shown below is a minimal working example of my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin = 2.54 cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\setlength{\parskip}{12 pt}
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label = (\alph*)]

\item

\newtheorem*{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{lemma}
Every continuous solution of $f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$ has the form $f(x) = x^c\ \forall\ c \in \mathbb{R}$.
\end{lemma}

\begin{proof}
Let $f(x) = g(\ln x)$, then $g(\ln x + \ln y) = g(\ln x)g(\ln y)$.

Now, let $g(x) = e^{h(x)}$, then $e^{h(\ln x + \ln y)} = e^{h(\ln x) + h(\ln y)}$.

$\implies h(\ln x + \ln y) = h(\ln x) + h(\ln y)$

This is Cauchy's functional equation, which has continuous solutions of the form $h(x) = cx$.

$\implies g(x) = e^{cx}$

$\implies f(x) = x^c$
\end{proof}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

However, my list appears like this:

[image: List formatting issue]

**Issue**

I think my problem is quite self-explanatory - I would like my lemma to start on the same line as the (a). How can I tweak my code to achieve this?

Comment: It will be possible but it seems a very unusual layout to have a titled structure like a lemma or theorem as part of a numbered list (certainly not a layout that the theorem environments were designed for)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see. The reason is because, as mentioned, I am doing an assignment, so you can imagine, there is, say Question 1, with parts (a), (b) and (c), Question 2 with its own parts etc. I only use this lemma in Question 1 part (d), so that is why the lemma is introduced in the list. How would you suggest I rectify this problem then i.e. if I insist that the lemma must start on the same line as the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must, you must...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin = 2.54 cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\setlength{\parskip}{12 pt}
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}

% dont do the assignments inside an environemnt that just makes things
% even harder
\newtheorem*{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label = (\alph*)]

\item 

\mbox{}\vspace{\glueexpr-\parskip-\lastskip-\baselineskip}

\begin{lemma}
Every continuous solution of $f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$ has the form $f(x) = x^c\ \forall\ c \in \mathbb{R}$.
\end{lemma}

\begin{proof}
Let $f(x) = g(\ln x)$, then $g(\ln x + \ln y) = g(\ln x)g(\ln y)$.

Now, let $g(x) = e^{h(x)}$, then $e^{h(\ln x + \ln y)} = e^{h(\ln x) + h(\ln y)}$.

$\implies h(\ln x + \ln y) = h(\ln x) + h(\ln y)$

This is Cauchy's functional equation, which has continuous solutions of the form $h(x) = cx$.

$\implies g(x) = e^{cx}$

$\implies f(x) = x^c$
\end{proof}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Right. That works! Thank you :) I like your comment, though :P - how then would you advise I format my answers for such an assignment?

Comment: @EthanMark it's a long time since I had to deal with anything that might be called an assignment, so feel free to ignore me. In a published article the theorem/lemma would probably be under a (sub)section heading aand everything would be flush left and the issue wouldn't arise.

Comment: Ahahahaha. Alright I shall play around with some different layouts when I have the time then :)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, wouldn't `\glueexpr` be more appropriate than `\dimexpr` here?

Comment: @Circumscribe I could claim that's what I wrote? :-)